# How to Bind two properties in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I am trying to experiment with angular bindings, I am stuck with a weird situation.. I need to bind two properties - here 'code' and 'title' are the binding properties

```
<app-title-component fxFlexFill [title]="code + title"></app-title-component>
```

This works fine!
I get the value of concated code and title value in the screen.

Now I wanted to have a static text between the two bindable properties
Say, I want the result to be

CodeValue - CodeTitle Value

How to do that? Is there a way to do binding using string interpolation?

Comment: `<app-title-component fxFlexFill [title]="code + ' - ' + title"></app-title-component>`

Comment: Define a getter in your component, cleaner than embedding string logic into your template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are two ways you can get this required result. Starting with a very simple method mentioned within the comments.

```
<app-title-component fxFlexFill [title]="code + ' - ' + title"></app-title-component>
```

secondly you can use string interpolation looking like so. Be sure to be using back ticks (  ` ) for this interpolation, else it will be ignored.

```
<app-title-component fxFlexFill [title]="result"></app-title-component>
```

within your template

```
public get result(): string
{
    return `${this.code} - ${this.title}`;  
}
```

[Here is an article looking at How Angular can deal with string interpolation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/template-strings/).

Comment: sorry dropped an edit, jumped the gun. thanks for pointing it out : -)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply define a getter in your component as follows:

```
class FooComponent {
  title:string;
  code:string;
  get formatedTitle(){return `${this.code} - ${this.title}`;}
}

<app-title-component fxFlexFill [title]="formatedTitle"></app-title-component>
```